# DOM Manipulation with existing large DOM

Tags: jquery, dom

In my webpage I am calling one webmethod on click on Load More button and that webmethod gets data from database and create one big HTML by loading lots of user controls lets say 40-50 user controls. And then this HTML is returned in javascript where I am appending this html to an existing div's innerHTML. This div initially have data in it so I am appending more data when user clicks on load more button.

Now issue is that for couple of click its working ok.. but after that it becoming slow as DOM is getting bigger so manipulations are expensive now. I looked into elements count which is 20000. But I checked element count for facebook also when lots of data is being displayed. Its having count of 50000. With this 50000 count facebook is running fine with no performance issues. But my site is hanging with 20000 elements.... not sure what the issue is... is this really related to elements?

Please help me.

Thanks

Deepak

Comment: Are you saying your web browser is crashing because there are too many elements on the page? If so, I would say something has gone horribly wrong during the design process. Why would a user even want so much information on one page?

Comment: are you using an update panel?

Comment: Show us some code. Or thankfully a link. In my experience, 20,000 DOM elements is something terribly gone wrong.

Comment: Facebook has a lot of really good engineers who have worked for years on optimizing their UI.  You should not expect your code to operate with the same level of efficiency to what their's does. So I guess what I am saying is don't bite off more than you can chew in the short term.  Limit your functionality to what you can make work well in the short term.  Then, as you figure out how to optimize your code, then look to add more functionality.

Answer (score 0):

It may be.  More likely however it is the (in)efficiency of your code, or how you're handling the DOM manipulation, iterations, etc.